# looping My Selenium Python webdriver code beginner

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, webdriver

I am a beginner and I wrote my first webdriver selenium python code. My question is how can I loop this code infinitely- I want the webdriver to close and then RE-open to continue the same code over and over. Can I add some kind of loop at the end of my code in order to start it up so i can leave my PC and not have to run it each time manually?

**** I want the webdriver to open and close so i can use a diff proxy each time***** Thank you

`

```
from seleniumwire import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains


options = {
   'proxy': {
      'https': 'XXXXXXXXX:3402',
      'no_proxy': 'XXXXXXXX:3403'
   }
}

driver = webdriver.Chrome('your_absolute_path', seleniumwire_options=options)


driver.get('https://www.google.com')

driver.implicitly_wait(30)

driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="/XYZXYZ").send_keys("HI")

time.sleep(5)

driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="/XYZXYZ").click()

driver.close()
```

`

Couldnt find anything online for this-stuck

Answer (score 0):

You can use While loop:

```
while True:
    options = {
       'proxy': {
          'https': 'XXXXXXXXX:3402',
          'no_proxy': 'XXXXXXXX:3403'
       }
    }

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()), seleniumwire_options=options)
    driver.get('https://www.google.com')
    driver.implicitly_wait(30)
    driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="/XYZXYZ").send_keys("HI")
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="/XYZXYZ").click()
    driver.close()

    # add a condition to quit the loop, like:
    if <condition>:
        break
```